# Proving the existence of an integer $n$ such that $2^n=123456789...$

Tags: arithmetic, dynamical-systems

How to prove that it exists an integer $n$ such that the decimal expansion of $2^n$ starts with $123456789$?

Comment: I think it can be done by using Pigeon-Hole Principle but I am not sure how can it be done.

Comment: How does this relate to the dynamical systems tag?

Comment: @Michael The question is from a document studying « les systèmes dynamiques » which is the French translation of « dynamical systems ». And indeed, the question can be looked at the locus of the a particle having the motion $n \mapsto 2^n$ in $\mathbb R$.